# SceneManager.LoadScene does not work in Unity 4.6?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

SceneManager.LoadScene is not working in Unity version 4.6.1. even though I have put `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;` at the top of my script.

What is the problem here, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 4):

SceneManager was introduced as part of Unity 5. It is not part of the 4.6 API. Look at [`Application.LoadLevel`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html) instead.